# Make sh executable as like exe in window

Tags: linux, shell, debian-based

I have one Shell script file. Inside it, I have create one text file in same folder where sh file is placed.

I want to run sh file on double click. When user double click on sh file then sh file will be execute and one text file should be generated in same dir.

I know i can make executable file using: `chmod +x myfile.sh`
but problem is:

> when I run this file on other Machine or same Machine with different
>   drive, I Need to make again executable. I want behavior just like "exe
>   file" in Windows.

Comment: What type of file system are you copying around this script that it loses its executable bit?  Try passing around a `tar` archive and unpacking it from `tar`, that might preserve the bits.

Comment: woolstar@ i am using ubuntu 12.04. i make executable file on this machine and copy it on pendrive and when run it from pendrive on other machine(My friend's machine-Ubuntu 10.04) it is not work.

Comment: Is the pen drive formatted FAT? or ext3?

Comment: it is "vfat" formatted

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the file to a drive whose filesystem doesn't support the Linux permissions model, you will lose these permissions. The solution is to use a Linux-friendly filesystem instead (reformat the drive, use e.g. `ext2` filesystem), but a less intrusive workaround is to store the file in a container which does preserve permissions (such as a `tar` file) and extract it from there to the target system(s).

If you need to support users who can only learn to click and drag with the mouse, only the first option is viable.

If the target systems have Internet access, perhaps the simple way forward is to put the file on a server, and just put a text file with the download URL on the stick.

Comment: trpleee@ I tried it also. I was put my file on server and put on link to download it. After download file, When i double click on file , Process still going but nothing happen.

Comment: To the extent I can decipher your description, sounds like an unrelated problem. If the downloaded file has the correct contents and the correct permissions, I would suggest we are done here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you right click the file and select `properties`. Check the box that says `Allow executing file as a program`.

Comment: I have done it also. But it is not working. I need to go terminal and change permission through: chmod +x myfile.sh

Comment: If it's not working. Maybe the file you're executing was not owned by your current user. Try to use chown <username> myfile.sh